# Java 8 streams: match and add parameters from one list to another

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I am kinda new to streams and lambda. Looking for a tidier code for this use case.

I have two Lists of Object types

```
class Employee{
   long empId;
   String empName;
   String deptName
}
```

and

```
class Department{
   long deptId;
   String deptName;
   long empId;
}
```

Initially Employee list is populated only with `empId` and `empName`.
And Department list populated with all the fields `deptId`,`deptName`,`empId`.

I have to populate corresponding `deptName` into Employee list from the Department list.

This is what I did.

1. Made a map of `empID` and `deptName` from departmentList
2. Iterate and match from the map

```
Map<Long,String> departmentMap = departmentList.stream()
                .collect((Collectors.toMap(Department::getEmpId, Department::getDeptName)));
employeeList.forEach(emp -> {
if(departmentMap.containsKey(emp.getEmpId())){
        emp.setDeptName(departmentMap.get(emp.getEmpId()));
}
});
```

Is there a cleaner or tidier way to handle this in Java 8/10?

Comment: If all argument constructor and new list was a possibility, you could have used streams such as `List<Employee> updatedEmployees = employeeList.stream()
                .map(emp -> new Employee(emp.getEmpId(), emp.getEmpName(),
                        departmentMap.getOrDefault(emp.getEmpId(), emp.getDeptName())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` or you are better with your current approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like:

```java
List<Employee> employeeList = List.of(new Employee(1, "John"), new Employee(2, "Emily"));
List<Department> departmentList = List.of(new Department(1, "Dept 1", 1), new Department(2, "Dept 2", 2));

Map<Long, Department> departmentMap = departmentList.stream()
                .collect(toMap(department -> department.empId, department -> department));

employeeList.forEach(e -> e.deptName = departmentMap.get(e.empId).deptName);
```

You can use [Collectors.toMap()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap) to turn your `List` into a `Map` and then just go over your `employeeList` and assign each employee its department.